# Securing Spring Web Public REST API

Tags: java, spring, rest, security

I am at a state where I finished a **REST API** from a functional point of view using `@RestController`,`@RequestMapping`, etc. with Spring.

---

Now I am asking myself on how to secure this api?
As it is the backend for a simple web page there is no username/password approach, as there will not be someone logging in.

---

Nevertheless I want to be safe against e.g. bruteforce approaches.

---

As I am completely new to this topic I tried to do some research, but most of the time a username/password authentication is assumed. In my case it would be somehow the client application itself that has to authenticate?

---

What is the state of the art approach of protecting such an API (logically and from a spring point of view)?
I found some stuff about `Digest Authentication`, but I am not 100% sure if that's the way to go.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by brute force approaches.. are u taking about ddos attacks etc?

Comment: Yes, correct! Sorry for the misleading naming.

Comment: I think such protections are best provided by Firewalls and on network layer.  We shouldn't deal with them on application layer.

Comment: You are right, I think this is correct. Thank you!